# Get count of selected vertices in UV pane

Tags: uv, vertices

I would like to know the number of vertices that I have currently selected in the UV pane.

The stats bar on top of Blender only shows me the overall vertex count.

How could I show the number of currently selected vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable UV syncing, selected UV coordinates will be echoed onto your 3D view, and the header will show you how many you have selected.

[image]